# Replace all attributes from HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have an event listener which listens for 'copy' event.
now from the copied data, i want to remove all attributes that are within the DOM and also remove any additional white spaces within the code.

```
document.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
  let target = event.target, selectedText = '';
  if (target.nodeName === "INPUT" || target.nodeName === "TEXTAREA") {selectedText = target.value.substring(target.selectionStart, target.selectionEnd);}
  else{ 
const selection = window.getSelection();
      if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
          const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
          const clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
          const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
          tempDiv.appendChild(clonedSelection);
          selectedText = tempDiv.innerHTML;
      }
  }
  selectedText = selectedText.replace(/(class|id|style|data-*|src|alt)\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/g, ''); // change code here
  selectedText = selectedText.trim();
  
  console.log (selectedText.length);
  console.log (selectedText);

  if (selectedText.length > 0){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "copy-event",data: selectedText});
  }
});
```

sample code below

```
<section class="box_section mobile-collapse" data-nid="2279" data-cms-title="What is ASD? " data-cms-anchor="1">
  <h2 id="part_2279">What is ASD? </h2>
  
    <div>
<p>Autism spectrum disorder (ASD) is a neurological and developmental disorder that affects how people interact with others, communicate, learn, and behave. Although autism can be diagnosed at any age, it is described as a “developmental disorder” because symptoms generally appear in the first 2 years of life.</p>

<p>According to the <em>Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM-5)</em>, a guide created by the American Psychiatric Association that health care providers use to diagnose mental disorders, people with ASD often have:</p>

<ul><li>Difficulty with communication and interaction with other people</li>
    <li>Restricted interests and repetitive behaviors</li>
    <li>Symptoms that affect their ability to function in school, work, and other areas of life</li>
</ul><p>Autism is known as a “spectrum” disorder because there is wide variation in the type and severity of symptoms people experience.</p>

</div>

</section>
```

expected result below

```
<section><h2>What is ASD? </h2><div>
<p>Autism spectrum disorder (ASD) is a neurological and developmental disorder that affects how people interact with others, communicate, learn, and behave. Although autism can be diagnosed at any age, it is described as a “developmental disorder” because symptoms generally appear in the first 2 years of life.</p><p>According to the <em>Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM-5)</em>, a guide created by the American Psychiatric Association that health care providers use to diagnose mental disorders, people with ASD often have:</p>
<ul><li>Difficulty with communication and interaction with other people</li>
<li>Restricted interests and repetitive behaviors</li>
<li>Symptoms that affect their ability to function in school, work, and other areas of life</li>
</ul><p>Autism is known as a “spectrum” disorder because there is wide variation in the type and severity of symptoms people experience.</p></div></section>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `data-*` should be something like `data-[\w-]*` but using regex for html parsing is [just unreliable](/a/1732454). Use DOM methods like getAttributeNames + removeAttribute to clear the attributes inside a document.createTreeWalker loop. If you really want to use a regex then at least use an outer regex matcher for the tag, then replace the attributes using the second regex for attributes inside the callback.

Comment: What, if anything, should happen with possible newlines within the nodes? For example, if your `p` elements contain `\n`, should that be preserved?